# Why is my setState is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `react` component that I have created.  In this component, I call a function that updates the state generically:

```
updateCheckbox: function(name, value) {
    this.setState({name: value});
},
```

I have checked the `value` of this function and I see that the correct `value` is getting called and set.  The `render` function is then called, because the state has just been set.  When I go inside the `render` function, the `state` has not been updated.

I realized this is because I have updated the `state` generically.  If I put the actual name of the `state` in the `setState` function, then everything is updated as it should.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)(which is added in ECMA 6) to use the value stored inside `name` variable

```
updateCheckbox: function(name, value) {
    this.setState({[name]: value});
},
```

OR the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for wider browser support

```
updateCheckbox: function(name, value) {
    var temp={};
    temp[name]=value;
    this.setState(temp);
},
```

Comment: Please note that the brackets here have nothing to do with bracket notation.

Comment: @FelixKling you mean bracket notation is only said if used like `obj_name[prop]`.right?

Comment: @FelixKling, so what does it represent?

Comment: In the spec it's simply called "ComputedPropertyName". http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer . And no, the brackets don't have anything to do with arrays either, it's simply part of the object literal syntax now.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you so much. It's so clear to me now( I was so wrong before).