# Why is this.setState is not updating this.states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code `this.setState` doesn't seem to be updating `this.states` but re-render is triggered. `componentWillUpdate` callback is also showing the correct parameters.

```jsx
class TimeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.states = {
      percentage : 50
    }
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    console.log("componentWillUpdate currentstate")
    console.log(this.states);
    console.log("componentWillUpdate nextstate")
    console.log(nextState);

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let component = this;
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    console.log(this.states);

    this.setState({
      percentage : 70,
      test : 10101010
    }, () => {
      console.log("callback setState");
      console.log(this.states);
    })

  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.props.onClick(component.props);
  }

  render(){
    console.log("render");
    console.log(this.states);
    let component = this;
    let { buttonInnerRadius, buttonOuterRadius, x, y } = this.props
    return (
      <Group onClick={component.handleClick.bind(component)}>
        <CircularBar x={x} y={y} innerRadius={buttonInnerRadius} outerRadius={buttonOuterRadius} ref="bar" percentage={this.states.percentage}></CircularBar>
        <Circle x={x} y={y} radius={buttonOuterRadius}></Circle>
      </Group>
    )
  }
}
```

So here is the result

[image: my program's output]

Am I doing something wrong here ? 
setState have worked before somewhere else I coded

If I do stupid things like

```jsx
this.states.percentage = 70
this.states.test = 101010
this.forceUpdate()
```

It works just fine but that looks like a bad idea

so far I have checked out

[Why is my setState is not working? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597155/why-is-this-setstate-not-working)

[Why is 'this.setState' not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968776/why-is-my-setstate-is-not-working)

Comment: It's called `state`, not `states`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a typo in your code. A component's state is called `state`, not `states`.

Comment: thanks that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Maybe my brain just go full prop is props so state must be states back then.

Answer (score 1):

#### @Tholle is precise, `this.state` exists inside React class module. There is nothing like `this.states`.

```
/**
 * Module for creating composite components.
 *
 * @class ReactClass
 */
var ReactClass = {

  createClass: function(spec) {
    // To keep our warnings more understandable, we'll use a little hack here to
    // ensure that Constructor.name !== 'Constructor'. This makes sure we don't
    // unnecessarily identify a class without displayName as 'Constructor'.
    var Constructor = identity(function(props, context, updater) {
      // This constructor gets overridden by mocks. The argument is used
      // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

      if (__DEV__) {
        warning(
          this instanceof Constructor,
          'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' +
          'JSX instead. See: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/legacy-factories.html'
        );
      }

      // Wire up auto-binding
      if (this.__reactAutoBindPairs.length) {
        bindAutoBindMethods(this);
      }

      this.props = props;
      this.context = context;
      this.refs = emptyObject;
      this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;

      this.state = null;
```

You can put inside the `this.state` *anything* you need via the **`setState`** method. Here I am setting the state `a` with the value `'a'`.

```
 this.setState({ a: 'a' });
```

---

> If I do stupid things like
>
> ```
> this.states.percentage = 70
> this.states.test = 101010
> this.forceUpdate()
> ```

#### This would be dynamically adding `states` property. However, this is not smart.

The states should always be set using the `setState` method and never directly even if you improve the typo. This should be done asynchronously like explained in here.

```
File: react/docs/js/react.js
1220: /**
1221:  * Sets a subset of the state. Always use this to mutate
1222:  * state. You should treat `this.state` as immutable.
1223:  *
1224:  * There is no guarantee that `this.state` will be immediately updated, so
1225:  * accessing `this.state` after calling this method may return the old value.
1226:  *
1227:  * There is no guarantee that calls to `setState` will run synchronously,
1228:  * as they may eventually be batched together.  You can provide an optional
1229:  * callback that will be executed when the call to setState is actually
1230:  * completed.
1231:  *
1232:  * When a function is provided to setState, it will be called at some point in
1233:  * the future (not synchronously). It will be called with the up to date
1234:  * component arguments (state, props, context). These values can be different
1235:  * from this.* because your function may be called after receiveProps but before
1236:  * shouldComponentUpdate, and this new state, props, and context will not yet be
1237:  * assigned to this.
1238:  *
1239:  * @param {object|function} partialState Next partial state or function to
1240:  *        produce next partial state to be merged with current state.
1241:  * @param {?function} callback Called after state is updated.
1242:  * @final
1243:  * @protected
1244:  */
1245: ReactComponent.prototype.setState = function (partialState, callback) {
1246:   !(typeof partialState === 'object' || typeof partialState === 'function' || partialState == null) ? "development" !== 'production' ? invariant(false, 'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.') : _prodInvariant('85') : void 0;
1247:   this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState);
1248:   if (callback) {
1249:     this.updater.enqueueCallback(this, callback, 'setState');
1250:   }
1251: };
```

As explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):
*The only place where you can assign this.state is the constructor.*

Direct setting the state will not re-render a component, and this should be the idea behind the `setState()` method.

Also React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.